# How to remove empty lines from a string in bash using parameter expansion?

Tags: bash, variables, parameters, expansion

I have the following variable.

```
echo "|${VAR1}|"
```

which returns

```
|
ABC

XYZ|
```

How can I remove the empty lines, preserving line breaks and using parameter expansion? So that it would become

```
|ABC
XYZ|
```

p.s.: I know how to do it using pipe sed, but I would like to avoid the extra SED process:

```
VAR1=`echo "${VAR1}" | sed '/^\s*$/d'`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the leading newlines, then replace any consecutive newlines with a single one.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

var='
ABC

XYZ'

expected='ABC
XYZ'

shopt -s extglob
var=${var##+($'\n')}
var=${var//+($'\n')/$'\n'}
[[ $var == $expected ]] && echo OK
```

Answer (score 1):

read the lines of the variable into an array, and remove the empty elements

```sh
var1=$'\nABC\n\nXYZ'
mapfile -t arr <<<"$var1"

declare -p arr                  # => declare -a arr=([0]="" [1]="ABC" [2]="" [3]="XYZ")

for ((i = ${#arr[@]} - 1; i >= 0; i--)); do
    [[ -z ${arr[i]} ]] && unset "arr[i]"
done

declare -p arr                  # => declare -a arr=([1]="ABC" [3]="XYZ")

(IFS=$'\n'; echo "|${arr[*]}|")  # in a subshell for temporary IFS setting
```

```
|ABC
XYZ|
```

Comment: `for i in "${!arr[@]}"` would also work, as that dumps all the indices at once before the loop starts.

Comment: Holy cow, what a mess. I invite you to just edit it next time.